# Regex quantifiers and character classes

Tags: java, regex, quantifiers

There are examples and descriptions of regex quantifiers  in Java Tutorial.

Greedy - eats full string then back off by one character and try again

> ```
> Regex: .*foo  // greedy 
> String to search: xfooxxxxxxfoo
> Found "xfooxxxxxxfoo"
> ```

Reluctant - start at the beginning then eat one character at a time

> ```
> Regex: .*?foo  // reluctant quantifier
> String to search: xfooxxxxxxfoo
> Found "xfoo", "xxxxxxfoo"
> ```

Possessive - eats the whole string trying once for match

> ```
> Regex: .*+foo // possessive quantifier
> String to search: xfooxxxxxxfoo
> No match found
> ```

They are ok and I understand them, but can someone explain to me what happens when regex is changed to the character class? Are there any other rules?

> ```
> Regex: [fx]*
> String to search: xfooxxxxxxfoo
> Found "xf","","","xxxxxxf","","","",""
>
> Regex: [fx]*?
> String to search: xfooxxxxxxfoo
> Found 15 zero-length matches
>
> Regex: [fx]*+
> String to search: xfooxxxxxxfoo
> Found "xf","","","xxxxxxf","","","",""
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It applies the quantifier (greedy, reluctant/lazy, possessive) to the entire character class.
This means it will match (greedily, lazily, etc) each literal character in the character class.

```
Regex: [fx]*
String to search: xfooxxxxxxfoo
Found "xf","","","xxxxxxf","","","",""
```

So it looks for zero or more of `f` or `x`. The engine finds `xf` which matches. It also matches on the empty string around the two `o`'s. It then matches the consecutive `x`'s because it's zero **or more** of `f` or `x`.

I would check out [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/rN0wS1/2) for more detail on regexes, especially the debugger portion on the left sidebar

Comment: why does it start from the beginning if it's greedy then?

Comment: All regexes start from the beginning of the string. `greedy` just means it matches as much as it can first. [Take a look here](http://regex101.com/r/rN0wS1/3). Compare that with a [lazy quantifier](http://regex101.com/r/rN0wS1/4)